# Markdown: Math-environments inside code block

Tags: markdown

Some markdown engines support mathematic expressions (= LaTeX) by wrapping them in $-signs.
When writing pseudo code, it would be practical to also have them inside of the code environment like this:

````
```
foreach $u \in V$ do
  u.d = $\infty$
```
````

Is there a way to escape the code block, so that those math-expressions do render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems not to be possible.
The solution I came up with was just to copy the unicode character from a site like [this](https://unicode-table.com/en/) and paste it in the code block.

This way, you can create an output like this:

```cs
foreach v ∈ Adj[u] do
    if v.color == white then
      v.π = u
      DFSVisit(G,v)
```

Not the perfect solution, but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set your font to a monospaced alternative and remove the block wrapper, or use in-line code wrappers around your mathematical expressions.